# eclipse - default build path for new maven projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, buildpath

How does `eclipse` decide which `JRE`/`JDK` to use for new `maven` projects?

When I create a **new** maven project in eclipse I get 3 warnings about the build path.

```
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5.
There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

The `jre` that was installed with the eclipse package seems to be 17.0.3.
[image: installed jres]

So why is eclipse giving new projects this `J2SE-1.5`?
**Where** does eclipse take this information from?

I know I can go into the properties for the project and change the `java build path` or configure it in the `pom.xml`, but when I create a new project it will select the wrong `jre` again.

Comment: E.g. when the `pom.xml` contains `<properties><maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target></properties>`.

Comment: "So why is eclipse giving new projects this `J2SE-1.5`?" - Because that's the default of Maven that Eclipse follows.